# Optimize if -else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, jdbc

I am writing a query for searching records from db. I pass 3 values to the method . I want to write my query in such a way that the condition  for that column is appended in the query whose passed corresponding value is non-null. I have ended up with messy if else statements. Is there a way to optimize it?

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(projectId)) {
  sql.append(" UPPER(CIRC.PROJECT_ID) like ?");
}

if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(circuitId)) {
  if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(projectId)) {
    sql.append(" AND");
  }
  sql.append("  UPPER(CIRC.CIRCUIT_ID) like ?");
}

if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(orderRef)) {
  if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(projectId) || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(circuitId)) {
    sql.append(" AND");
  }
  sql.append("  UPPER(CIRC.ORDERID) like ?");
}

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
ResultSet rs = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
  if (connection != null) {
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(projectId)) {
      ps.setString(1, "%" + projectId.toUpperCase() + "%");
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(circuitId)) {
      if (StringUtils.isEmpty(projectId)) {
        ps.setString(1, "%" + circuitId.toUpperCase() + "%");
      } else {
        ps.setString(2, "%" + circuitId.toUpperCase() + "%");
      }
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(orderRef)) {
      if (StringUtils.isEmpty(projectId) && StringUtils.isEmpty(circuitId)) {
        ps.setString(1, "%" + orderRef.toUpperCase() + "%");
      } else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(projectId) || StringUtils.isEmpty(circuitId)) {
        ps.setString(2, "%" + orderRef.toUpperCase() + "%");
      } else {
        ps.setString(3, "%" + orderRef.toUpperCase() + "%");
      }
    }
```

Note: This question is not a subject of orm/jdbc. Also please ignore hard coding.

Comment: "messy if else statements. Is there a way to optimize it." Step 1: format your code. It's just messy currently and incomplete.

Comment: [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @AndyTurner I  think complete code is irrelevant to question.I have formatted the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect the clauses in list and join with " AND ", and then collect the args in another list, e.g.:

```
    // Uncomment out on Java 6
    // import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

    List<String> clauses = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(projectId)) {
        clauses.add("UPPER(CIRC.PROJECT_ID) like ?");
        args.add(projectId);
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(circuitId)) {
        clauses.add("UPPER(CIRC.CIRCUIT_ID) like ?");
        args.add(circuitId);
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(orderRef)) {
        clauses.add("UPPER(CIRC.ORDERID) like ?");
        args.add(orderRef);
    }

    // Java 8 (comment out for Java 6)
    sql.append(clauses.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" AND ")));

    // Uncomment for Java 6
    // sql.append(Joiner.on(" AND ").join(clauses));

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        if (connection != null) {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); ++i) {
                ps.setString(i+1, "%" + args.get(i).toUpperCase() + "%");
            }
        }
    }
```

On Java 6 comment out the Java 8 line and uncomment out the Java 6 lines. Also add [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) to your project.

Comment: What type of object is clause?

Comment: This wonn't work for me. I am using java 6 but it is for java 8

Comment: Can you tell me for java 6?

Comment: @Shweta I've edited my answer to include the changes necessary for Java 6.

Comment: please declare clauses in ur answer. What type of variable is it? I mean its class , if its list what is the generic type of list?

Answer (score 2):

You could write your appends like so:

```
  sql.append(" UPPER(CIRC.PROJECT_ID) like ? AND ");
```

and finish of the complete clause with:

```
sql.append(" 1=1 ");
```

Comment: Thank you .Can you help optimize  **ps.setString(1,..** this part.

Comment: You could try something along the line of 'getParameterMetaData', check the ammount of parameters you current have in your preparedstatement and use that as your index.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main (String[]args){ 
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append ("Select * From Table where ");        
    String projectId = "11";        
    String circuitId = "";        
    String orderRef = "33";

    sql.append(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(projectId)?" UPPER(CIRC.PROJECT_ID) like ?":"");
    sql.append(sql.toString().endsWith("?") && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(circuitId)?" AND":"");
    sql.append(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(circuitId)?" UPPER(CIRC.CIRCUIT_ID) like ?":"");
    sql.append(sql.toString().endsWith("?")&& StringUtils.isNotEmpty(orderRef)?" AND":"");
    sql.append(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(orderRef)?" UPPER(CIRC.ORDERID) like ?":"");
    System.out.println(sql.toString()); 
}
```